# How to get type information for Mongodb's emit function for Map-Reduce

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm using TypeScript on a node.js application.  I was just trying to setup a map-reduce call but I get the error:

`Cannot find name 'emit'.`

...anywhere I try to use the emit function in the map phase.  I've got `@types/mongoose` and `@types/mongodb` installed, and can use type information from those files but there doesn't seem to be a definition for 'emit'.  (I've got `aggregate` working in the same file along with various queries so in general things are working fine - I'm using mongoose if that makes a difference).

Note that I'm just asking for the type info to get rid of the red underlines in my IDE.

I have even added the following, and while the references work, it doesn't solve the problem:

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts" />
```

Anyone have the `emit` function for mogodb map-reduce typed correctly in TypeScript?

Comment: The `emit()` runs on the "server", which knows nothing of running typescript. So it's kind of a pointless exercise. Whilst you are allowed to supply JavaScript functions as arguments when running a native JavaScript program, from the "server" point of view, these just get sent across as "strings" anyway. So if you are declaring external to the inline method, you may as well just define `any`. And there is no "strict" call signature anyway other than basic key and value.

Comment: I get the error in my IDE even when just using `emit` directly in the inline method.  When you say "you may as well just define `any`" what specifically do you mean?  I can just put `var emit:any;` so it is ignored and all will be well?  That's good enough for me, I just want to get rid of the error in the IDE.